# How to set up tabular data problem type in Vertex AI？

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

When I use the REST API to create a Vertex AI Dataset, the type of the dataset is tabular data. There is a problemType required in the request body, but there is no tabular type. How should I set it?

Types in the document below：

Required. Problem type of the SavedQuery. Allowed values:

- IMAGE_CLASSIFICATION_SINGLE_LABEL
- IMAGE_CLASSIFICATION_MULTI_LABEL
- IMAGE_BOUNDING_POLY
- IMAGE_BOUNDING_BOX
- TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_SINGLE_LABEL
- TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_MULTI_LABEL
- TEXT_EXTRACTION
- TEXT_SENTIMENT
- VIDEO_CLASSIFICATION
- VIDEO_OBJECT_TRACKING
  You can see types without tabular data，What should I do？

The reference url is https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.datasets/create

I try set one of above options,but failed.

Answer (score 0):

A similar post was already answered in the [Google Cloud Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/How-to-set-up-tabular-data-problem-type/m-p/636838/highlight/true#M3041) forum.

> It looks like Tabular Data dataset creation is not yet implemented for this type of request body, I would suggest to file a feature request for this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1130925
>
> Also this reference might be useful for your query, creating dataset for [forecast model](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/forecasting/create-dataset#create_an_empty_dataset_and_associate_your_prepared_data).